# Parsing log file in hadoop using java program

Tags: java, hadoop

I have written a small map program to read through the log files and look for a word called 'extract'. Only if the word is found, it should write the line to the context object. But somehow i see all of the lines in the output file. Here is my code

```
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
            if(word.find("extract") >= -1) {
                context.write(word, null);
            }
        }
    }
```

Can you please let me know what im doing wrong?
Thanks,aarthi

Comment: If you want to write line to the context; why you are trying to add word ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to write the line to the context; here is the code template

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String line = value.toString();

    if (line.contains("extract")) {
         context.write(value,null);
    }

}
```

Comment: HI, Thanks for the input. I get a null pointer exception when i pass null to the context's write method. When i replaced the second parameter null with something like 1, the program works. However it adds the second parameter to the output in every line. Is there a way around this?

Comment: can i know what you would like to achieve ?

Comment: there are several log files that each run to several GB. Im looking for certain lines in the log files that match my criteria. As a sample, im looking for line that have the word 'extract' in it.

Comment: instead of writing it to the context, directly try to write to another file. Context.write method takes key and value as parameters. That is the reason you are getting second parameter.

Comment: where would i store such a file in hadoop? my apologies if the questions are basic.